# Gnuplot command `STATS_skewness` undefinde

Tags: statistics, gnuplot

I'm analyzing some data with gnuplot I obtained in measurements. I'm trying to express the kurtosis and skewness. First, I use `stats 'data.dat' u 2` so gnuplot get the statistical summary. I can use e.g. `print STATS_mean` or `STATS_stddev` and see these measure. However, when I type `print STATS_skewness` or `print STATS_kurtosis` I read the error `undefined variable: STATS_kurtosis`. They seems to be valid options, that are listet at [gnuplot docummentation](http://www.bersch.net/gnuplot-doc/stats--statistical-summary-.html)!

So, can I not use these commands? How do I obtain the skewness and kurtosis otherwise?

Comment: That seems odd. If you type `show variable STATS` after executing the stats command, does it not show a value for STATS_kurtosis?  Are you running a really old version of gnuplot (some version older than 5.0)?

Comment: my version is 4.6 patchlevel 2. `show variable STATS` only shows about 16 records, the one I'm interested in not included.

Comment: well, you were looking to the documentation of a newer gnuplot version. If, for some reason, you can't update to at least gnuplot 5.0, you probably will have to implement it yourself. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ethan pointed out, my compute cluster uses an outdated gnuplot version that does not have the skewness or kurtosis implemented. Since I can not update it, I moved my analysis to my notebook.